# Create a web-browser window using wxpython

Tags: wxpython, buttonclick, python-webbrowser

How am I going to create web browser-like window in wxpython wherein every time a button is clicked, this window will display all the files I want to download from an ftp site.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at wx.html2 which contains the webview widget. This is included in wxPython 2.9. You can use that for your custom web client. For downloading files, I recommend using urllib or requests. You can read about that here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/

Comment: I already tried this and it's working but I don't know how to turn/make it into a GUI.

Comment: There's an example in the wxPython demo that you can follow.

Comment: Where could I find that demo about the GUI File Download Manager?

Comment: No, no. Get the wxPython demo and follow its examples on how to use the html webview widget. If you had done some searching on Google, you might have also found this: http://ftpcube.sourceforge.net/ which is a wxPython FTP client. You can probably still use it for ideas even if it is old.